# C# Checking variables whether defined or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started learning asp.net and c#.

Let say I have a session like this:

```
Session.Add("username","me");
```

At a later section, I wanna learn whether that session has been defined. How can i do that ? I tried to do this :

```
if(Session["username"]){
   // some code
}
```

but of course it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of error message do you get? What kind of type has the content that you put into the session? Does `if` supports this kind of type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {

        }
```